# Как передать значение из PostMapping на отображение в GetMapping

Tags: java, html, spring, mvc, thymeleaf

Контроллер:

```java
@GetMapping("/next")
String next(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("name", test);
    return "greeting";
}

@PostMapping("/next")
String postNext(@RequestParam(name = "test", defaultValue = "test") String test) {
    System.out.println(test);
    return "redirect:/next";
}
```

Шаблон:

```html
<form th:action="@{/next(test=${name})}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" th:value="${name}">
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Мне нужно узнать значение на странице и работать уже с ним может есть другие мысли как его получить

Comment: Если ответ верный, то Вы можете отметить его как правильный. См. справку:  [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

#### Замечания

В шаблоне присутствует следующая строка:

```html
<input type="hidden" th:value="${name}">
```

Здесь Вы добавляете скрытое поле формы, но при этом вы не указываете атрибут name, который потребуется для получения отправки значения и для обращения к нему.

В целом у Вас здесь имеется небольшая путаница с атрибутами, где-то name, где-то test...не надо так. Очень легко запутаться и потерять необходимое значение.

С Вашего позволения в своем решении я привел все параметры к следующему виду:

```
наименование: name
значение по умолчанию: test
```

Соответственно везде все параметры, атрибуты, имена переменных связанные с данным параметром будут называться "name".

В итоге нам для начала необходимо указать название параметра передаваемого в форме (name="name"):

```html
<input name="name" type="hidden" th:value="${name}">
```

Также меня смутила следующая строка:

```html
<form th:action="@{/next(test=${name})}" method="post">
```

В ней вы пытаетесь передать параметр запроса через адресную строку.
Что с этим не так:

- Во-первых передача данных через параметры адресной строки используется в GET, а не POST запросах
- Во-вторых данные формы должны передаваться с помощью полей, а не через адресную строку, в противном случае вы рискуете получить конфликт при передаче данных

Поэтому передачу параметра я настоятельно рекомендую убрать:

```html
<form th:action="@{/next}" method="post">
```

#### Передача параметра

Если тебя интересует передача параметра именно с помощью редиректа, то можно воспользоваться классом `RedirectAttributes` и передать параметры запроса через него.

И перехватить параметры запроса в GET с помощью `@RequestParam`

```java
@GetMapping("/next")
String next(
    @RequestParam(name = "name", defaultValue = "test") String name,
    Model model
) {
    model.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "greeting";
}

@PostMapping("/next")
String postNext(
    @RequestParam(name = "name", defaultValue = "test") String name,
    RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes
) {
    System.out.println(name);
    redirectAttributes.addAttribute("name", name);
    return "redirect:/next";
}
```

Шаблон:

```html
<form th:action="@{/next}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" th:value="${name}">
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Также советую для тестирования изменить тип поля на text:

```html
<input type="text" name="name" th:value="${name}">
```